# Function php in_array dont campare array as needle in haystack

Tags: php, arrays

I suspect a problem with the in_array function. I have read many time the doc, test it, and always the same thing append

here is a working code :

```
$tohide = '141'; 
$objterm = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
global $catlist;
$catlist = array();
foreach ($objterm as $singleterm) {
    array_push($catlist, $singleterm->term_id);
}
if (!in_array($tohide,$catlist)) {
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
}
```

that piece of code output all item BUT category 141... cool, work fine...
Now, i like to get a array as item to hide

```
$tohide = array('141','134'); 
$objterm = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
global $catlist;
$catlist = array();
foreach ($objterm as $singleterm) {
    array_push($catlist, $singleterm->term_id);
}
if (!in_array($tohide,$catlist)) {
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
}
```

This DONT work... it output everything... dont filter any of the item i try to hide.

Now the question is... how to show every item that are NOT in the array to hide... i have no idea ! maybe another php function do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
if(!array_intersect($tohide, $catlist)){
  ...
}
```

You'll get an array with any items from `$tohide` that are present in `$catlist` (an empty array will evaluate to false)